# Can you break an RSA modulus if you know $k \cdot \phi(n)$ where $k$ is a large prime?

Tags: rsa, factoring

Given some RSA modulus $n$, can you factor $n$ if you are given $k \cdot \phi(n)$ where $k$ is also a large prime?

(Of course, you could factor $n$ if you were given $\phi(n)$ [as discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791340/on-factoring-and-integer-given-the-value-of-its-eulers-totient-function), but that approach does not work when you cannot factor $k \cdot \phi(n)$, right? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** we can factor an RSA modulus $n$ given $n$ and $k \cdot \phi(n)$, including where $k$ is a (reasonably) large prime. We just use $f\gets k \cdot \phi(n)$ instead of $f\gets e\,d-1$ in the algorithm of [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62487/555).

The algorithm is heuristic, and I do not claim a rigorous proof of the distribution of the runtime. Also, a larger $k$ tends to make it more costly. But in practice it works fine for $k$ of size comparable to $n$.