# How to decrypt c when e is not co-prime with phi(n) and e is non-prime

Tags: rsa, public-key, modular-arithmetic

In RSA, I want to know a way to be able to retrieve all possible plaintexts $m$ given a ciphertext $c$, $\phi(n)$, $n$ and $e$. The decryption exponent $d$ can not be generated due to the fact that $e$ is not co-prime with $\phi(n)$.

In fact, the $e$ I have is not even prime(it is specifically $1024$ in this case and thus it is even so it is certainly guaranteed to have a gcd greater than $1$ with both $p - 1$ and $q - 1$), which is the main reason I am asking, as every single method that I have found online that can be used to find possible plaintext when $gcd(e, \phi(n)) > 1$ assumes that $e$ is prime, which is completely invalid in my scenario. Anyone knows how to get all plaintexts when $e$ is not relatively prime to $\phi(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the question states, in RSA, $e$ needs not be prime. Indeed, customary $e$ like $65537$ and $3$ are prime; but as long as $\gcd(e,\phi(n))=1$, we can compute a working $d$ as $e^{-1}\bmod\phi(n)$.

Hint if indeed $\gcd(e,\phi(n))\ne1$: knowing $n$ and $\phi(n)$, factor $n$ (see e.g. [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62487/555)). Then, using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), transform the problem of finding all the solutions $m\in[0,n)$ to $m^e\bmod n=c$ into several simpler such problems with $n$ replaced by ${p_i}^{r_i}$, where the $p_i$ and $r_i$ are the primes dividing $n$ and their respective [multiplicities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)), so that $n=\prod{p_i}^{r_i}$.

Additional hint: in the specific case of $e=2^k$ (as in the question), and if $n$ is the product of $\ell$ distinct odd primes (that is all the $r_i$ are $1$, and $n$ is odd), there will be up to $e^\ell$ solutions. They can be obtained as sketched above, additionally using [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) recursively to depth $k$ for each of the $\ell$ sub-problems obtained by CRT, then recombining the $\ell$ sets of up to $e$ solutions to these sub-problems, using the CRT.

Comment: This gives hints rather than a detailed answer, because the question could be an exercise, homework, or a CTF.