# How do I retrieve a number which has been multiplied with a random number?

Tags: randomness, prime-numbers, factoring

I have a 1024-bit number $n$ obtained by multiplying two 512-bit randomly generated prime numbers $p$ and $q$.

Then there's $\phi = (p-1)(q-1)$, which is another 1024-bit number.

I do not have $\phi$ but I do have the result obtained by multiplying $\phi$ with a random 1024-bit number.

I need to retrieve $p$ and $q$. I know how to get to $p$ and $q$ values starting from $\phi$ but I don't know how to extract $\phi$ from the product I have.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Do you need the original $\varphi$ or can you also make do with some multple of $\varphi$? (In the latter case you don't need to recover $\varphi$...)

Comment: Very nearly a duplicate of [Algorithm for factoring knowing RSA private key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52736/555) and [Why is it important that phi(n) is kept a secret, in RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5791/555). Hint: One way is to factor $n$, then compute $\phi$. A concise description of Miller's algorithm to solve this is Dan Boneh's [Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf#page=3), proof of fact 1.

Comment: Also: depending on the [smoothness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) of the random number and $\phi$, there may be other ways noticing that $n\approx\phi$.

Comment: I need to retrieve $p$ and $q$ and in order to do that I need to somehow extract $\phi$ from the number I have. @fgrieu if I could factor $n$ then I would not need to compute $\phi$ as I would already have $p$ and $q$. Also, the Miller's algorithm seems to not be applicable to this problem as I do not have $d$ or $e$. It is not an RSA problem.

Comment: @SEJPM In fact I already have a multiple of $\phi$, can I extract $p$ and $q$ directly from it?

Comment: In the proof of fact 1 [linked](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf#page=3) in my [first comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/187924), did you miss the similarity of _"$k$ is a multiple of $\varphi(N)$"_ with your case? The algorithm there is close to the one justifying the mention _"Miller [\[6\]](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/Papers/Mi75.pdf) has shown that $n$ can be factored using any multiple of $φ(n)$"_ in the [original RSA article](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf#page=13). I also stand by my second comment.